# rtl8822bu fails after Ubuntu 19.10 update

Tags: drivers, kernel, 19.04, make, 19.10

Started with Ubuntu few months ago. My HW is in older machines too slow to handle Windows, so Ubuntu 19.04 was right solution. I'm not so familiar with Ubuntu, but I see necessity of compiling drivers in some cases.

This specific error I now have in my laptop Acer Aspire One 725-C62kk - running Kernel 5.3.0-23-generic . For my USB-WiFi I use `rtl8822bu` driver (modified that it can handle my ASUS AC-53 Nano dual band USB-dongel) - the advice I took from Internet. Worked well so far.

Normally after kernel-updates, this driver must be re-maked with following commands  and it works :

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8822bu
```

Now after 19.10 update, it doesn't.

During `make`, I get following results (after `make clean`, of course):

---

[Listing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2r9357b7zlcgbc/rtl8822bu-issue.txt?dl=0) during make ..

---

Former I used advice from [this_thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395729&p=13782927#post13782927) .. that helped before update 19.10

Answer (score 0):

Please try this process instead. It builds, albeit with a few possibly harmless warnings, on my 19.10 system.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms git
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
sudo dkms add ./rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.3.1
sudo modprobe -r rtl8812au
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer - the cilynx driver does compile, when I used USB2.0 port on my laptop. In USB3.0 port it failed that way, that it did compile, but became very unstable. Compiling while dongel is in USB2.0 port worked fine, and works stable. Even though I moved the dongel in USB3.0 after that it works stable. However the speed the dongel and network delivers is reduced markably.

Comment: Seems that it cannot handle a situation where the 2,5G and 5G wireless connection from access point uses the the same connection parameters like name and password. The dongle couldn't connect at all, but the internal 2,5G wireless still could. Somehow the use of the dongle is not possible in these occations. I couldn't sadly make the difference if the dongle tried on 5G or to 2,5G  wireless or it had a missmatch with the internal wireless network (Realtek rtl8188CE) .. is there a way to switch internal wireless network card off without screwing the backplate away? @chili555

Comment: You might try switching the internal off in Network Manager by applying Airplane Mode, although that might also switch off the USB; try and see. Please try renaming the 2.4gHz and 5gHz segments in the router to see if it helps; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

Comment: First of all thank you for your advice (again) .. Airplane mode switches both wifis' off at once. At home I have different segments with different naming, but at the place where I use my laptop I am not the network admin .. next time I just try to see what happens when I remove the internal wifi-card .. maybe this week on friday I know more. Basically I hope that the 5G would be the primary selection and with only on signal weakness the 2,5G would be used instead. @chili555

Comment: Please try binding the wifi to the 5gHz as here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192099/19-10-ubuntu-automatically-connects-to-a-weaker-wi-fi/1192112#1192112 Please try disabling the internal temporarily with; `sudo ip link set wlp3s0 down` Of course, substitute your exact interface if not wlp3s0. In `ip addr show` the internal will probably be wlp-something and the USB will probably be wlx-something. P=PCI; X=eXternal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your advice in 

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192099/19-10-ubuntu-automatically-connects-to-a-weaker-wi-fi/1192112#1192112

.. and got a horrible feeling, that I am using your precious time for nothing. Deeply apologize that. In my small head never came an idea that my "connection is (can be) refused." ... maybe cause the numerous attempts I had.

Comment: That thought came into my mind after arriving back home. I recorded what happened there and put the listings into my dropbox as [iwlist-scan.txt][1]and [nmcli.txt][2].
Basically next week there are 2 possibilities to try again, and I have a strong feeling you @chili555 have done your utmost. So thank you very much for your excellent support and I humble peg your pardon causing such a trouble.
 ...


  [1]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/etau7oif5k0mta0/iwlist-scan.txt?dl=0
  [2]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzt2rs70r7l5tm9/nmcli.txt?dl=0

Comment: You have caused no trouble at all. Please see: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yW68SXfPrs/

Comment: thank you deeply.. I'll sure try the suggested method next week again. In the settings I was able to see 3 instances of that same id (after once recompiling cylinx-driver today) , but in the network connections there was only one instance been seen. The funny thing was that the old internal wifi was always able to connect. That's where I started thinking I might be refused. @chili555

Comment: I tried to connect with the last tips provided. The connection is either refused or it has something with creating new instances on every connection attempt I do (it asks know password every time). Basically, I do not suffer of this behaviour - but I know there are similar connection setups used in hotels around the world. For my normal personal use I have no issues anymore with this driver. Thank you @chili555 for excellent support and nerves.