# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Not connecting on Specific Router

Tags: wireless, internet

I have a laptop that has run Ubuntu 20.04 for a few years and so far no problems. Installed a new home router a few days ago and the laptop won't connect to the router. Every other device in the house connects. I am currently using the wifi via my phone as a hotspot to my laptop.

I've been searching for an answer or at least somewhere that points me in the right direction here, but coming up short.

After following the directions [`here`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos?noredirect=1&lq=1) to run a terminal command for wireless info, my [pastebin is here](https://pastebin.com/nyseQhev):

Edit: I have managed to connect intermittently, and have done a pastebin with the results from this connection [here](https://pastebin.com/bXxam89L)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your pastebin indicates thet you are connected perfectly to POCO X3 NFC. Is the new router some different SSID? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @chili555 reading the post I would conclude that `POCO X3 NFC` is OP's mobile phone hotspot that they use as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Does the problematic wifi network show up on the laptop's settings panel, and the problem is only with establishing connection, or it does not even show up? (I was thinking along the lines of whether the laptop is such an old piece of hardware that it cannot see a wifi that's broadcast on the 5gHz frequency... Anyhow, try out what happens if you make the router broadcast its wifi signal at 2.5gHz...)

Comment: What channel do other devices suggest that the new router is on?

Comment: @Levente  the wifi network shows up, and occassionally will connect, but it doesn't appear to let any data through, if that makes sense. 

I'm not sure how to make the router broadcast at a different frequency? would that change it's quality for other people who are using the router?

Comment: could you reveal this network ssid, so that we can look for it in your pastebin?

Comment: If you live in an apartment building and all your neighbours broadcast strong signals on, say, 2.5 gHz, then choosing 5 gHz for your wifi will enable you to free yourself from the interference. But the same thing can happen the other way around: maybe eveyone broadcasts at 5 gHz and hardly anyone at 2.5 gHz, then choosing 2.5 gHz will will be beneficial. The communication is happening digitally, so interference from other broadcasters would mostly manifest itself in a higher rate of "packet loss" (some data chunks need repeated sending), that translates to longer wait times.

Comment: You can set the frequency in the router's admin interface, which is usually a "website" that you can access by visiting a specific IP address in your browser, _**while** connected to the wifi network provided by your router_. That special IP address will be probably found on the backside of the router (along with the username/password). Since your laptop cannot reliably connect to it, you will have to carry out this adjustment by using another device. Nevertheless, I would also look into another direction, namely whether the problem is driver-related.

Comment: @Levente Thank you. At the moment I'm connected to the router (it's suddenly working), but this has happened before and then it will just stop (while all other devices are ok)

Answer (score 0):

We notice that you are connected to the SSID named VM5962767. We also notice that there is another SSID with the same name.

This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like VM5962767_2.4 and VM5962767_5.

After making these changes, reboot the router. Then select the 5 gHz SSID where you will get better speeds.

If you are unable to access the router's administrative pages, then bind your wireless to the 5 gHz segment by its MAC address like this: [19.10 Ubuntu automatically connects to a weaker Wi-Fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192099/19-10-ubuntu-automatically-connects-to-a-weaker-wi-fi/1192112#1192112)

Comment: Thank you, this might make sense, as the wifi seems to connect well when it's closer to the router. Do I rename the access points via the router or via my ubuntu system?

Comment: Rename in the administrative pages of the router.