# Deauthenticated Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID

Tags: wireless, 22.04

I have multiple computing devices in my home (2 Ubuntu laptops, 2 windows PCs, smart TVs, tablets, phones, etc.).

I am having an issue on only one of my ubuntu devices (no other devices having any issue, other Ubuntu device is 20.04), where I am getting deauthenticated periodically, dropping my WiFi connection. It appears to be trying to re-authenticate to a different MAC address when it drops, though the only difference is the last position (which switches between 2b, 2c, and 2d). My theory is that my wifi router using both 2.4G and 5G SSID to automatically provide connection, which is where the different MAC addresses are coming from, but I don't get why only this laptop is getting "PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID".

Note: This laptop was updated to 22.04 a few months ago, and that is when this behavior began.

---

Laptop hardware:
5th Gen Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

---

output from *lspci -knn | grep Net -A3*

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 88)

Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:0130]

Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

Kernel modules: iwlwifi

---

dmesg logs:

````
[ 1870.651427] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2b (try 1/3)
[ 1870.659866] wlp4s0: authenticated
[ 1870.663374] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2b (try 1/3)
[ 1870.669000] wlp4s0: RX ReassocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2b (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1870.676917] wlp4s0: associated
[ 1870.748498] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2b
[ 1904.099981] wlp4s0: disconnect from AP xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2b for new auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[ 1904.165004] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[ 1904.175741] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[ 1904.183957] wlp4s0: authenticated
[ 1904.186853] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[ 1904.190067] wlp4s0: RX ReassocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1904.193381] wlp4s0: associated
[ 1904.230410] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[ 1907.494012] wlp4s0: deauthenticated from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=8)
[Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[Mon Jan  9 09:01:34 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Mon Jan  9 09:12:07 2023] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=6)
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[Mon Jan  9 09:56:56 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: deauthenticated from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (Reason: 7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Tue Jan 10 02:16:41 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: disconnect from AP xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c for new auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: RX ReassocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:35 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Wed Jan 11 13:02:38 2023] wlp4s0: deauthenticated from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Wed Jan 11 13:03:23 2023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:44 2023] wlp4s0: disconnect from AP xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c for new auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:45 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:45 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:45 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:45 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:45 2023] wlp4s0: RX ReassocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:45 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:45 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Wed Jan 11 13:42:48 2023] wlp4s0: deauthenticated from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:27 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:27 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:27 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:27 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (try 1/3)
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:27 2023] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=6)
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:27 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:28 2023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[Thu Jan 12 10:38:28 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: disconnect from AP xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2c for new auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (try 1/3)
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: RX ReassocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: associated
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:01 2023] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d
[Thu Jan 12 13:12:05 2023] wlp4s0: deauthenticated from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2d (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 2):

> My theory is that my wifi router using both 2.4G and 5G SSID to
> automatically provide connection, which is where the different MAC
> addresses are coming from

I suspect that you are quite correct. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

If you are unable to access the router's administrative pages, then bind your wireless to the 5 gHz segment by its MAC address like this: [19.10 Ubuntu automatically connects to a weaker Wi-Fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192099/19-10-ubuntu-automatically-connects-to-a-weaker-wi-fi/1192112#1192112)