# computer dropping wifi connection sometimes multiple times in a session, but no apparent pattern Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: wireless, login, password, security, broadcom

Running a MacBook Air, version 7.2 and Ubuntu 23.04. I have a decent wifi router with good signal strength. I awaken the computer and when the computer connects to my wifi network I begin my session -- except sometimes I get prompted to enter my network password. Sometimes I will get prompted multiple times before I'm connected. Once connected, I will check my e-mail or start my browser (Firefox)...and then the wifi connection drops. I'll re-select my network and connect. Sometimes not. Sometimes the connection will drop again, and may even prompt me for the network password again - sometimes multiple times, before finally tying a knot that will not slip.I don't know if it is a Broadcom issue, or what. I am aware of a log viewer in my utility folder, but there are 4 different logs to view and am unsure what to look for. I'm in over my head, again. This was also happening in Ubuntu 22.04 but a little worse in that version, I think.

sudo dmesg | grep wl

```
[    4.040518] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.040539] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    4.044551] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.185420] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[    4.829818] wl 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[  102.210383] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[ 9860.650013] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[ 9860.650020] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[ 9873.840173] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[12267.334289] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[12267.334293] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[12277.491675] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[12484.036753] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[19550.153526] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[19550.153528] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[19560.384033] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[19723.594961] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[26827.339099] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[26827.339102] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[26837.113573] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[28064.870938] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[28064.870941] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[28074.913482] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[28158.877043] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[28491.216848] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[28491.216851] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[28501.112859] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[32788.083879] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[32788.083881] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[32797.585768] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[33029.680743] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[33029.680748] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[33057.620050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
```

$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

```
Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0117]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

$ nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID             MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BA>

- ```
    xx:xx:xx:EA:29:0E  CXNK001D2761     Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄>

    xx:xx:xx:EA:29:15  CXNK001D2761     Infra  108   540 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄
  ```

The wifi dropping issue seems to have been mooted by recent updates. There have been no drops since August 1.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: Let's also see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `nmcli device wifi list` Please redact the MAC addresses with xx:xx:xx. Please only show your own network(s).

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator - the logs are informative, if I understood them. I can see that things are happening or failing to happen. I could copy and post some log entries, but unsure of which and how many lines. I suspect more than one kind of failure or kerfuffled operation happening.

Comment: @chili555 it seems I have 2 different possible connections in my wifi transmitter and I can see 2 different signal strength indicators on my screen, according to which connection is engaged. I do not know what part of the computer/wifi unit environment decides which connection will be used.

Comment: @tomkoehler Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Lok at `ip route`. Read `man ip ip-route`.

Comment: "I do not know what part of the computer/wifi unit environment decides which connection will be used." You clicked "CXNK001D2761" which told Network Manager to connect to it. However, there are two of them so NM roams looking for a stronger connection. Hence the disconnect. Bind NM to the 5 gHz segment as I suggested and the drops should stop.

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

If you don't have administrative priveleges for the router, I suggest that you bind to the 5 gHz segment by its MAC address like this: [19.10 Ubuntu automatically connects to a weaker Wi-Fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192099/19-10-ubuntu-automatically-connects-to-a-weaker-wi-fi/1192112#1192112)

Comment: I'll not deliberately do anything to/with the router, as it is part of the equipment installed by my fiber provider. I will do the binding thing, but will have to read the information you directed me to, multiple times to sort it out. ty

Comment: Following the suggestions given me have been frustrating. apparent success was short-lived. subsequent failures continue. Network Manager logs reveal yellow-highlighted warnings I do not comprehend. Other terminal data have some disconcerting messages I'm not able to understand, yet. Will pause this pursuit and reboot for fresh logs and better notes.